# Good approach to handle get large dataset from database using jpa repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am talking about 4 million data in one single query

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/getData" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String getData (@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") String start,
            @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false, defaultValue = "0") String end, ModelMap model) {
        
        
            List<Object> getDataList = repo.getData(start, end);            
            model.addAttribute("getDataList ", getDataList);
            model.addAttribute("showDownload", true);
            model.addAttribute("start", start);
            model.addAttribute("end", end);
            
        
        return "getData";

    }
```

This method fetches me 2.2 million data at one time. How this piece of code can be optimize?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM table where date between :start and :end", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> getData(@Param("start") String start, @Param("end") String end);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to return all data in single response?

Comment: Optimized for what?

Comment: it takes more than 4 minutes to fetch 100000 records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pagination`.

Your API and query will change to accept some necessary information required for pagination. Example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0;
```

[Reference](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/)

It might not be a good idea to return such a huge dataset in response.
The huge response can cause network trouble.